# Is there a library or a model in ML I could use to transform text into structured content like a table

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning

I'm a newb to the field of ML. I'm trying to learn about NLTK and SciKit, as a part of learning process I'm trying to convert certain text into a structured data but I'm lost after a certain point.

**Input:** Price variation every year: 2018 2017 2016 Grocery $ 100 $ 150 $ 200 Gas $ 40 $ 50 $ 60 Utilities $ 36  $ 33  $ 31 Clothes $ 100  $ 100  $ 110 
**Output:**

[image: Strucured content]

I really appreciate if anyone could provide me pointers, documents or links I could make use of to convert the text into a structured format. 
I tried using nltk by tokenizing and getting the POS tags, it is a brute force method and was not successful. I tried splitting the string at regular intervals but is not fruitful as it won't work if I change the string.

Comment: Take a look at pandas

Comment: @Alec I tried creating a dataframe with the string, but if I change the length of my string the data I'm writing into the DF is not consistent, is there anything particular in Pandas I can make use of?

Comment: you need the `io` and the `pandas`